# How to use ref of schema as oneOf/anyOf responses of an endpoint using springdoc-openapi?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, openapi, springdoc

I'm using *springdoc-openapi* and I defined a few schemas using **one of** my classes (so they don't have individual classes). I've defined them using *addSchemas* in `OpenAPI` bean as mentioned in this issue:

https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/685#issuecomment-636028451

It's something like this:

```
@Bean
public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
    return new OpenAPI().components(new Components()
            .addSchemas("ErrorOne", getSchemaWithDifferentDescription(ErrorObject.class, "ErrorOne")
            .addSchemas("ErrorTwo", getSchemaWithDifferentDescription(ErrorObject.class, "ErrorTwo")));
}

private Schema getSchemaWithDifferentDescription(Class className, String description){
    ResolvedSchema resolvedSchema = ModelConverters.getInstance()
            .resolveAsResolvedSchema(
                    new AnnotatedType(className).resolveAsRef(false));
    return resolvedSchema.schema.description(description);
}
```

Now I want to use these schemas in *oneOf* (or *anyOf*) using `ref` of them as possible responses of an endpoint. Something like this:

```
@PostMapping
@ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400",
                content = { @Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                        schema = @Schema(oneOf = {"ErrorOne", "ErrorTwo"})) }
        )
})
public HttpResponse myEndpoint(@RequestBody HttpRequest httpRequest) {
    ...
}
```

But the problem is that `oneOf` field in `@Schema` annotation **only accepts a list of classes**, and I can not use the ref of those schemas here.

1. Is there a way to link these schemas to *oneOf/anyOf* using their references in spring-doc?
2. And also I wanted to know is there a way to add some global responses as oneOf/anyOf responses for my endpoints (beside their own possible responses)?